Excel Formula for Longest Common Substring (LCS)
I've seen many solutions for finding the longest common substring (LCS) or longest shared text between two strings in other programs or languages, but not one that uses formulas in Excel. Posting my own solution here. Please feel free to add suggestions for how I could improve this formula -- Sarr seems particularly "bloated".

TL;DR

A1: target string
A2: comparator string
A3: mutual text to ignore


=LET(s1_adj,SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(A1),LOWER(A3),""),s2_adj,SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(A2),LOWER(A3),""),Sarr,MID(s1_adj,SEQUENCE(LEN(s1_adj)-1),SEQUENCE(,LEN(s1_adj)-1,LEN(s1_adj),-1)),CSarr,UNIQUE(TOCOL(MAP(Sarr,LAMBDA(a,IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(a,s2_adj)),a,""))))),SSarr,FIND(CSarr,TRANSPOSE(CSarr)),SSarrPROD,BYROW(IF(CSarr=TRANSPOSE(CSarr),1,IF(ISNUMBER(SSarr),0,1)),LAMBDA(row,PRODUCT(row))),TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,FILTER(CSarr,SSarrPROD<>0)))


This formula will return not only the LCS, but all common substrings (provided the substring is 2 or more letters long). It also supports removing from consideration specific mutual text within both substrings for easier analysis of longer strings.
How this works:

Lowercase both strings (SUBSTITUTE is case sensitive) then remove/ignore any specified mutual text
Create an array of all the substrings (letter sequences) in the target string
Try to FIND each substring within the comparator string, and return only the matching UNIQUE substrings (can have repeated letter strings). For example, a substring of "an" will appear at least twice within the array if the target string is "banana".
Further FIND and remove sub-substrings (since they would already be covered by the local LCS). For example, "an" is contained within "anan" for target text "banana".
TEXTJOIN remaining common substrings into a single cell of text.

